# Laplace's Equation with Neumann B.C. on disc

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve Laplace's equation with the following boundary conditions:

$On\hspace{0.1in}the\hspace{0.1in}disc\hspace{0.1in}of\hspace{0.1in}radius\hspace{0.1in}1,\hspace{0.1in} \triangledown u(x,y) \cdot N = |x| ,\hspace{0.1in} when \hspace{0.1in}x^2+y^2 = 1$

Would no solution exist, because a solution exists only when (for Neumann's boundary conditions)

$\iint \limits_{\delta \Omega}f(x)d\sigma = 0$

And in this problem $f(x) = |x|$, so the integral does not equal $0$?